# #VALUE error in concatenate when if is used

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate in XL. based on cell valued I want to change the value that needs to be added. I am getting #value error when i trying to run the below code.

Let us say i have 2.5 in A1, 500 in A2 in Cell B1 I want to concatenate if

```
=concatenate(if(find(".",A1),A1*1024,A1)," some more data", "some more data")
```

Can you please help me in fixing this issue.

many thanks in advance.

Thanking you,
Pradeep

Comment: `=if(a1-int(a1)=0,a1,a1*1024)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If excel is interpreting the **2.5** as a numeric value, then **FIND** will not work. You would be better comparing **A1** to **Round(A1,0)** to determine whether there is anything after the decimal point.